# Tracing SAT constraints in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I have some constraints involving Bitvectors that I believe should be `sat` even though Z3 produces the verdict `unsat`. I have managed to reduce them to a small example.

I tried tracing the solver by running `z3 -tr:sat test.smt` but did not get any traces (it just says `unsat`). Any ideas why this doesn't work, or an alternative to debugging this type of situation?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to label your constraints and then ask for an unsat core. This will allow you to see which (hopefully a small) set of constraints are found conflicting and debug from there. If you post your example, we can help with setting it up for unsat-core production.